# How to clear cache on UIWebView in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm using tableview to display different pdfs locally. For example;

```
pdf1 -> "1.pdf"
pdf2 -> "2.pdf"
pdf3 -> "3.pdf"
```

In my first click, there is no problem but when I tap again it loads different pdf. Ex: I tap pdf2 but it loads pdf1.

Can you help me in this issue, I'm new to swift..

Comment: Show us the code that you have try.

Comment: NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity = 0
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity = 0

Comment: Tried this but did not work for me, or where do I have to implement this

Comment: not this one the webviewload and tableview methods, also add this code by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it with ;

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity = 0
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity = 0
```

Also use like this;

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.web.com")
let url_request = NSURLRequest(URL: url,
    cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
    timeoutInterval: 5.0)

let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadRequest(url_request)
```

Thanks